# Application not loading on Tomcat 7 server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

I am running an application on my Tomcat 7 server.  The server loads and runs but, when I enter `http://localhost:8080/ApplicationTest` I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ApplicationTest

type Status report

message /ApplicationTest

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

I have switched location in my properties and in Tomcat Server 7 settings under Server Location I have changed it to "Use Tomcat Installations".  But it is still not working, I even tried to reinstall the server.  I am using Eclipse Kepler and Tomcat 7, and running a vaadin web application.  I do not get any errors in my tomcat logs, it is below:

```
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\;.
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TweetApp' did not find a matching property.
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 722 ms
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\docs
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\examples
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@2e901f36')
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\host-manager
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\manager
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2013 3:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1788 ms
```

So my question is how do I fix this problem, how do i run my application on my tomcat 7 server?  Below is my server.xml if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="TweetApp" path="/TweetApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TweetApp"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Below is my servlet-mapping in my web.xml

```
<!-- ================ Built In Servlet Mappings
========================= -->


  <!-- The servlet mappings for the built in servlets defined above.  Note  -->   <!-- that, by default, the CGI and SSI servlets are *not* mapped.  You    -->   <!-- must uncomment these mappings (or add them to your application's own -->   <!-- web.xml deployment descriptor) to enable these services              -->

    <!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mapping for the SSI servlet --> <!--
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.shtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
-->

    <!-- The mapping for the CGI Gateway servlet -->

<!--
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
-->
```

Comment: yes I just called it ApplicationTest in the question

Comment: What part do you want to see specifically of the web.xml?

Comment: Your config seems fine, but looking at the log, it doesn't seem like your application is being loaded. There's no statement like `Deploying web application directory `/ApplicationTest`. Have you extracted your war (or put it directly) in the webapps folder?

Comment: Which directory specifically should I look at?

Comment: Notice in the logs you have 5 statements saying `Deploying web application directory ...`. There should be a directory in `C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps` for your application. Is one there?

Comment: The folder exits but my application is not located in it

Comment: Then you need to generate a `war` of your application and put it in there with the same name as in your `server.xml`, ie. `TweetApp`. So, for example, `C:\Users\wa7sh\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\TweetApp.war`

Comment: I did this but it did not solve the problem, I even restarted the server and cleaned the tomcat working directory

Comment: Oh, you're running in Eclipse? Have you added the project by right clicking the server and doing Add/Remove?

Comment: Ya that did not fix it though

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with the following error "WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TweetApp' did not find a matching property."

Comment: org.eclipse.jst.jee.esrver does not exist in my .metadata/.plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with the application it seems that my server was working it was my application that was having the problem.  I am using the newest version of eclipse (kepler) and whenever I create new vaadin web application it defaults the configuration to "Vaadin 7, Java 6, Servlet 3.0", and this configuration for some reason did not auto create a web.xml file in the WEB-INF Folder.  To fix this I chose "Vaadin 7, Java 6, Servlet 2.4", which auto created the web.xml for me.  There is probably a better solution, but as of now this worked.  If someone posts a better solution I will choose their answer.

Comment: If this was the case then it is likely that in `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` the line `<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0" />` specified a different version than your application required. This throws an error in eclipse, but the user is not notified of this, unless he looks into the "Error Log"-View

Answer (score 2):

Assume your application is called `TweetApp`. Let's do some cleanup.

1. Right-click your server and `Delete` it.
2. Create a new Tomcat server instance and add `TweetApp` application to it.
3. In the Project Explorer, select the `Servers` folder, open your instance, and open `server.xml`.
4. Towards the bottom, there should be a `<Context>` element for it. Use the `path` attribute to build a `URL`.
5. Start the server.

For example, if `path` is `/TweetApp`, access your application at `localhost:8080/TweetApp/`.

If you want to make sure the application is started, I would recommend you register a `ServletContextListener` and put a log statements in its `contextInitialized()` method and make sure its printed when you restart the server.

Comment: there still seems to be a problem it starts but it is not loading the application.  Usually it should say /ApplicationName at the end of the log, but it is not doing that for me.

Comment: @abden003 If you've added it with the server's `Add and Remove...` utility, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem I did below and it worked.
1)I refreshed my project in the eclipse and then added the war file in the tomcat and then it worked.